# ¿Cómo enviar correo con link usando JavaScript Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html5-datalist

```js
$("#enviarCorreo").click(function () {
  var email = $("#email").val();

  if (email == "") {
    swal("error", "Ingrese su Correo", "error");
  } else {
  }
});
```

Quisiera enviar un enlace (link) de reseteo de contraseña por JavaScript.

Tengo la caja de texto para ingresar el correo pero no sé cómo verificar el correo ingresado y que a su vez me mande un correo indicándome el enlace (link) para el reseteo de la contraseña.

Este es el código HTML para ingresar el correo:

```js
$("#enviarcontrasena").click(function() {
  var email = $("#email").val();

  if (destinatarios == "") {
    swal("error", "Ingrese su Correo", "error");
  } else if (nombres == "") {
    swal("error", "Ingrese Su Nombre", "error");
  } else if (telefono == "") {
    swal("error", "Ingrese su Telefono", "error");
  } else if (asunto == "") {
    swal("error", "Ingrese el Asunto", "error");
  } else if (mensaje == "") {
    swal("error", "Ingrese el Mensaje que Desea enviar", "error");
  } else {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-contacto">
  <div class="contact">
    <div class="contact-main">

      <h3>Tu correo electrónico</h3>
      <input type="email" placeholder="tu@correo.com" class="" id="usuariorecuperar" required />

    </div>
    <div class="enviar">

      <div id="recuperandoclave"></div>

      <div class="contact-enviar">
        <button id="enviarContrasena">Recuperar</button>

      </div>
      <div class="clear"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Saludos, al dar click en el boton "enviarContrasena" deberias invocar a una funcion de JavaScript la misma que obtenga el email y sea enviado por ajax hacia un archivo php que sera el encargado de enviar dicho correo y retornar una respuesta para que muestres al usuario que se envio el correo con dicha info.

Comment: si lo tengo acabo de agregarlo pero el php que hace la accion no la conosco

Comment: se q en enviar correo se usa Email.send({ ]) ; no conosco mas nada para lo q estoy pidiendo

Comment: Lo mejor para hacer esto es por medio de Ajax. Revisa aquí mismo cómo funciona, aquí hay varias respuestas que lo explican. Luego intenta un código y plantea la pregunta si tienes dudas concretas sobre ese código.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos supongamos el siguiente escenario aqui sera desde donde se llene los datos necesarios para enviarlos por request hacia php:

```js
function enviarCorreo(){
  inputCorreo = document.getElementById('usuariorecuperar');
  correo = inputCorreo.value;
  if(correo == '' || correo == null){
   alert('ingrese el correo.');
   inputCorreo.focus();
   return false;
  }
  
  //haciendo el request hacia php
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //ruta archivo donde recibira mi correo
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "miArchivo.php", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 || this.status === 200){ 
        console.log(this.responseText); // echo from php
    }       
 };
  //correo enviado a mi archivo/ruta php
 xmlhttp.send("correo=" + correo);
  
  
}//end function enviarCorreo
```

```html
<div class="form-contacto">
  <div class="contact">
     <div class="contact-main">
           <h3>Tu correo electrónico</h3>
           <input type="email" placeholder="correo@ejemplo.com" class=""  id="usuariorecuperar" required />
   
      </div>
      <div class="enviar">
        <div id="recuperandoclave"></div>
        <div class="contact-enviar">
        <button id="enviarContrasena" onclick="enviarCorreo();">Recuperar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

si te fijas al **button** he agregado un evento **onclick** este invoca una función **javascript** que sera donde recoja los datos para ser enviados hacia PHP:

**miArchivo.php ** para este caso de envio de correo uso la libreria PHPMailer:

```
<?php
//donde recibo el correo enviado por el request
$correo = $_POST['correo'];

$mail = new PHPMailer(); //instanciamos php mailer
$mail->IsSMTP(); // habilito SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; //me permite mostrar errores el modo debug
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // habilitar autenticacion
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";//por defecto de gmail
$mail->Port = 465; // puerto por defecto o el 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com"; //mi correo de gmail
$mail->Password = "password"; //mi clave de gmail
$mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com");//desde donde se enviara el correo
$mail->Subject = "Recuperacion clave";
$mail->Body = "hola aqui va tu mensaje de correo";
$mail->AddAddress($correo); //destinatario

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo json_encode( 'Error enviando correo');
    //echo "Error al enviar correo: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo json_encode( 'Correo enviado');
 }
```

como vez con esto podras enviar un correo debes adaptarlo a tus necesidades, no te olvides de incluir la librería **phpmailer**:

[PhpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: coloque lo siguiente al cod 

include ('PHPmailer/src/PHPMailer.php');

y me indica que hay un error en la linea 

$mail = new PHPMailer(); //instanciamos php mailer

Comment: es porque no esta bien tu ruta de phpmailer